# VBA - Outlook: Send message from one of multiple mailboxes

Tags: email, vba, outlook, exchange-server

Here is my problem:
- my client has multiple accounts in Outlook 2010
- each account has multiple mailboxes

Example:
- Account A: email@address.com
- under neath of that account he has the following mailboxes associated:
1. Support support@address.com
2. Contact contact@address.com
....

What I need to accomplish is to send email using VBA and have the message being sent as FROM contact@address.com. My client is using Exchange server. Unfortunately I do not have an Exchange server so I cannot test that.

Would you happen to have any idea?

Here is my current code used to set account (but only account not a mailbox associated / underneath of that account):

```
mailItem.sendUsingAccount = application.session.accounts.item("Contacts)
```

That part work and results with FROM: email@address.com. However, I do not know how to send an email so it reads FROM: contacts@address.com.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you can set the .SendOnBehalfOfName to the address you want to use.

Doing this will prompt the user to confirm access to the Mailitem.

Comment: I don't think that will work. I will but only sender's name will change. Unless I am missing something his inquiry was to change sender's address associated to each mailbox under each account.

Comment: My understanding is that in Outlook there is an account with email@address.com, for example. Of that account there are two mailboxes, support@address.com and contact@address.com. The OP wants to send some emails from support@address.com and some from contact@address.com. The only way prior to Outlook 2007 is to use the .SendOnBehalfOf property. In 2007 and going forward there is a property .SendUsingAccount but you need to now the Item number of the account.

For examples, I found the following page: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/account.htm.

Comment: .SendOnBehalfOf is working; just need to format it like: "Sender Name <sender.email@address.com>"...